# How to Change the Default .ppt viewer on Debian 8.5?

Tags: debian, gnome, multimedia

I would like to change WPS office's presentation the default viewer instead of  LibreOffice in my system. 
However, it could not find anything related to it in Search and not by *TweakTool*. 
One-liner would be great for the task.

### Testing GAD3R's proposal

The only limiting factor is the capability now to call the application (WPS presentation). 
You can call WPS writer by `wps` but nothing else came with the application package. I sent a question about it in their Linux [forum](http://wps-community.org/forum) but waiting their approval.

System: Debian 8.5 64 bit
Window manager: Gnome 3.14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new configuration file `defaults.list` under `/usr/share/applications`

Add your favorite application using the following format:

```
[Default Applications]
application/TYPE=LAUNCHER.desktop
```

There is an example:

```
[Default Applications]
application/ppt=wps.desktop
```

Verify it using `xdg-open` (as user):

```
xdg-open myfile.ppt
```

The list of the default application is sorted here:`/usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache`

**edit**

To launch wps presentation from the terminal , just type : `wpp`

Comment: The open question here is how to launch wps-presentation in terminal. There is `wps` which is for their writer. I sent the question to their forum and will be notified when it is accepted.

Comment: @Masi i edit my answer